# How to access scope function's parameter name with reflection

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I have a scope function on the `Reflect` class I created; this class will try to use reflection and set the `status` property value to the `InProgress` instance. My challenge here is accessing the name of `status` from the reflection side so I can set the private field by name.

```kotlin
Reflect(myExampleInstance) {
    on { status }.then(InProgress)
}
```

^ Here, I have `status` property that I have passed to the `on` function.

This is the reflection side:

```
inline fun <reified R> on(
    p: T.() -> R,
): OnGoingReflect {
    val declaredMember: KProperty1<out T, *> = instance::class.declaredMemberProperties.first {
        it.returnType.jvmErasure.java == R::class.java &&
            it.getter.call(instance) == p(instance)
    }
    return OnGoingReflect(instance, declaredMember.name)
}
```

I try to determine the name of `R` and set it by using the reflection. I solved the first problem by finding `declared member,` which works until I have two or more properties with the same type.

For example;

If I have `status2` with the same type, my method will return me `status` on the line of `declaredMember` because of the `first` call.

```kotlin
Reflect(myExampleInstance) {
    on { status2 }.then(InProgress)
}
```

The challenge is keeping the syntax of `on { propertyName }`. If I use `KProperty<T>` and `on { MyClass::status}` that solves it, but I am looking for a solution that does not make me change the syntax.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not possible with reflection. I doubt you can do this by a non-overkill way (reading the class file directly, hacking the compiler etc would probably work).

Comment: @Sweeper, it would be an overkill indeed; it would be great if I could use the ability of reflection.